Meaning of "raised the gratitude of her young vanity to a very good purpose" in Jane Austen's 'Emma'
I'm currently reading Emma by Jane Austen for the first time and I'm struggling to understand this excerpt from the beginning of Chapter 6:
"Emma could not feel a doubt of having given Harriet's fancy a proper direction and raised the gratitude of her young vanity to a very good purpose, for she found her decidedly more sensible than before of Mr. Elton’s being a remarkably handsome man, with most agreeable manners..."
It is specifically the phrase: "raised the gratitude of her young vanity to a very good purpose" that I am confused about.
I understand that Emma feels confident that she has made Mr Elton more appealing to Harriet, but what is "the gratitude of her young vanity" referring to here?

This was asked on English Language Learners before but nobody was able to answer it. My guess is that Austen uses gratitude where gratification would be more normal, but I've no evidence of that usage.

My wife, who is something of a Jane Austen expert, says that what is meant by "gratitude" there is more like "gratification." So the gratification of young vanity belongs to Harriet, who I suppose is pleased with herself for having attracted the attention of a potential suitor. (LPH writes below that "... the gratification of Harriet's young vanity has been enhanced, not for having attracted a potential suitor, but for having recently recognized in that suitor (through Emma's good offices) qualities that flatter her vanity.")
To quote my wife directly:

Emma is kind of a snob, valuing good looks and so-called refinement over authenticity. She is nudging Harriet to that way of thinking rather than responding to the honest and hard-working farmer to whom Harriet is becoming attached.

She further states that Austen uses many puzzling word choices, which can only be understood in context.

"for she found her decidedly more sensible than before of Mr. Elton’s being a remarkably handsome man …": the gratification of Harriet's young vanity has been enhanced, not for having attracted a potential suitor, but for having recently recognized in that suitor (through Emma's good offices) qualities that flatter her vanity.

Thank you. I'll add that to the text if you don't mind.

Are we understanding it as "... and [having] raised ..." ?

The closest definition I can find for vanity in the full OED is 4.a c1340– A vain, idle, or worthless thing; a thing or action of no value. But in the cited context, I assume Emma's vanity [project] is in fact Harriet (a person, not a thing). Whose gratitude (not gratification) towards Emma serves the useful purpose of causing her (Harriet) to have a higher opinion of Mr Elton (which definitely suits Emma).

Although this fact appears evident, I thought that your former phrasing could have made it a point much  less salient, while focusing on another reality. Of course, finally,  this "other reality" becomes conceivable. // I don't mind, on the contrary.

Thank you for your answer. So if we take "gratitude" to mean "gratification" in this context, what would "to a very good purpose" mean? What is the "purpose" referring to? Is it the purpose of the gratification?

That's covered in my wife's comment. The purpose is Emma's, which is to appeal to Harriet's vanity in order to tout her away from the farmer to the wealthier vicar. "You can do better than a farmer" is Emma's viewpoint.
